# ImportError: cannot import name requests

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I run .py code using terminal (ubuntu).

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                               
File "./twitterstream.py", line 15, in <module>                                                                                                                  
    from pip._vendor import requests                                                                                                                             
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>                                        
    from pip._internal.compat import WINDOWS                                                                                                                     
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>                                               
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions                                                                                                                         
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>                                             
    from pip._internal.index import (                                                                                                                            
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>                                                  
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
ImportError: cannot import name requests
```

All the errors are import errors. (pip)

I have tried reinstalling pip and python.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Have you installed the requests module?

Comment: Why are you using `pip` directly?

Comment: What is your PYTHON_PATH set to?

Comment: Yes, I have installed all the required packages,

Comment: I am using pip after installing it's package in my drive. Using it to import.

Comment: `$ pip install requests --user` and change `from pip._vendor import requests` to `import requests`.

Comment: If reinstalling `requests` and `urllib3` doesn't help, have a look [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251880).

Answer (score 3):

Little bit late, but just came to the same error as described here. However none of the suggested answers fixed my issue.

In my case `pip` was installed from OS' package manager (`python-pip` in Arch Linux) as well as requests (which is a dependency of the first).
After removing requests using pip (`sudo pip uninstall requests`) I ended up with this error.

Fixed by reinstalling using my distro's package manager (`pacman -Sy python-requests`).

Answer (score 2):

write on your terminal

```
pip install requests
```

beacause you didnt Installed Yet requests module , And you can install every Module by pip , pip install urlib2 , pip install readlines
, pip install termcolor etc//

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
from pip._vendor import requests
```

do this:

```
import requests
```

Your code is currently trying to import Requests from another program; that program has just reorganised all its code, so it's not surprising that this doesn't work any more.

Comment: That worked, but... there are so many more! It looks like I need to run the failing software on 18.04 instead of 16.04 (Ubuntu). Testing now....

Comment: Well even under 18.04 the upgrade to pip 19.x fails. But at least it gives me version 9.x instead of 8.x.

Comment: @AlexisWilke you may want to consider asking a new question; it sounds like you're having a different problem.

Comment: I found out that I had to run that software through Docker, then it worked. The setup is still invalid in my case, but otherwise the problem reported here is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

Pip 10.0.1 seems to be broken so there workaround for the moment is to pin pip at version 9:

```
pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

Otherwise, you need to get the latest version of pip, not the distro version as well as update your PATH:

```
export PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: For Python 2.7 `pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
` fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm got this error too on pip **10.0.1**.
On pip **9.0.3** there is no this error.

Comment: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, I hit this where any `pip` commands failed with that traceback.

This was due to a situation where I had upgraded most packages, but I neglected to upgrade the virtualenv related packages. These upgrades fixed it for me.

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
pip install --upgrade virtualenv-clone
```

this fixed pip commands, as well as the mkvirtualenv commands and such.

I see how several things might cause this, but this is one case that other users might help. In general, you may want to look for severely out-of-sync packages in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

i got the very same error. The problem was that i had deleted few folders named requests since it clashed with my Requests module in my python code. And then when i put the files back from the trash the pip3 list command worked fine.