# ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pip, python-requests

I am trying to uninstall pip using this command in macOS terminal:

```
pip uninstall pip
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'
```

I have tried many other commands, some unrelated to uninstalling `pip` such as:

```
pip --version
```

I have tried reinstalling the requests module with

```
pip install requests
```

All of them are result in the same error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'
```

Update: I tried to restore pip to pip 9.0.3 using

```
pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

and I tried importing requests. Both resulted in the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101692/importerror-cannot-import-name-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your pip version is 10.+ . It seems to be broken for some users.

what you can do is manually install a pip package from here [enter link description here](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).

Click on download files and download the `pip-18.0.tar.gz` file.

After that go to your downloads directory and expand the zipped file with a:

```
tar -xvf pip-18.0.tar.gz
```

it will expand it to a folder or dir named pip-18.0, do a:

```
cd pip-18.0
```

follow that by running the setup.py file with the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

It will work

Comment: work for me, but I followed install guide here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/