# Why isn't Pip working inside Python 3.6.9 Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, virtual-environment

**Specs:**

I am running a Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS Virtual Machine in HyperV (with a GUI installed).

I run this, and see it came with Python 3.8.5:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

**Goal:**

I need to:

1. Install Python 3.6.9 in my VM.
2. Go to an existing repository directory, and create a Virtual Environment for Python 3.6.9.
3. Install the following packages in the Python 3.6.9 Virtual Environment:

[image]

**Implementation:**

First, I downloaded the Python 3.6.9 source files from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-369/ and extracted them to a directory in my VM.

Then, I moved to said directory, and ran these commands:

```
$ time ./configure
$ time make                        
$ time sudo make install
$ time make clean
```

Then, I ran these commands, and saw that Python 3.6.9 is now installed.

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
$ python3.6 --version                                                                                                 
Python 3.6.9
```

Then I installed `pip` and it's package `virtualenv`. If I run these commands I get:

```
$ pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
$ virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.4.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
```

**I will test this on a new directory in my Desktop. Once I'm sure it works, I'll do it in the repository where I need it.**

I `cd` to my Desktop. Then I run this, to see where Python 3.6.9 is installed in my VM:

```
$ which python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

Then I run:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.6 testenv3.6
```

A new directory `testenv3.6` is successfully created in my Desktop. I `cd` to it and run:

```
$ source ./bin/activate
(testenv3.6) $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Everything seems fine.
Then I tried to run `pip install pandas`, and got this Error:

```
from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
ImportError: cannot import name requests
```

This also happened when I tried to install `numpy` or any other package. Seems similar to this: [ImportError: cannot import name requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101692/importerror-cannot-import-name-requests)

So I went to the file causing the Error. I can't remember exactly where it was, but I know I changed it from this:

```
from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
```

to this:

```
from pip._vendor import html5lib
import requests
```

Then I try to run `pip install pandas` or `pip install numpy` again, and I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
```

Once again I searched on Stack Overflow, and found this: [no module named zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib)

According to that URL's answer, I tried to run `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`. I get this:

```
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib python3.6-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 104 not upgraded.
```

If I try to run `pip install pandas` or `pip install numpy` again, the same error remains:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
```

I also tried `pip install zlib`, but it doesn't work.

I searched multiple Stack Overflow questions for similar issues. People said to:

- Downgrade and install a specific version of `pip`.
- Downgrade and install a specific version of `virtualenv`.
- Try to install the desired Python version from other sources.
- Try to install Pip from other sources.

Nothing seems to work.

I also noticed that the pre-installed Python versions were in `/bin/`, while my installation of python 3.6.9 was in `/usr/local/bin/`.
So I even tried moving the Python 3.6.9 file next to the other pre-installed Python versions.
So before, I got this:

```
$ which python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

And now, I get this:

```
$ which python3.6
/bin/python3.6
```

It still didn't fix it.

Now, after all my attempts, I might have installed Python in multiple places, and turned my system into a mess. I'm not sure.

Help?